# How to access Response object in NestJS GraphQL resolver

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

How can I access pass `@Res()` into my graphql resolvers?

this doesn't work:

```
@Mutation(() => String)
  login(@Args('loginInput') loginInput: LoginInput, @Res() res: Response) {
    return this.authService.login(loginInput, res);
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@Res()` is for HTTP Requests. To access to `res` object you'd need to first make sure it is added to the `context` for graphql by using `context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res })` in the `GraphqlModule`'s options, and then you can use `@Context() ctx` to get the context and `ctx.res` to get the response object

Comment: Is there any way to implement this in a type-safe manner, without explicit type assertions that use the `as` operator?